# What does this RegExp pattern /(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In Jquery there is a regexp patten definition

```
var rvalidbraces = /(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g;
```

this pattern matches strings like "abc,[" and "abc:[", but not for "abc^[".
So what's the meaning of this part in the pattern:

> (?:^|:|,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?: ... )` is a group (like `(...)`) that doesn't capture anything.

So your example `(?:^|:|,)` simply matches either the start of the text, a colon, or a comma.

> this pattern matches strings like "abc,[" and "abc:[", but not for "abc^[".

It sounds like you don't know what `^` means - in a regex, it means "the start of the string" (unless you've turned on multi-line mode, where it means "the start of the line").

Comment: I see. I know ^ means the start of a string or line, but i don't know it can be used in conjunction with |.

Comment: @dencey: It means start of string anywhere in a regex, except if it's inside a character class `[...]` :)

Comment: @Porges because if the `^` is the first character in the character class it means NOT and if it is not the first character it means a normal `^`

Answer (score 1):

- `()` means a capturing group
- `?:` if you place this in the front of a group it won't be captured, so the capturing group become only a group of characters.
- `^|:|,` means it matches the begin of the line (`^`), or a `:` or a `,`. The `|` is the seperator between these tokens.

Answer (score 1):

`(?:^|:|,)` means match ^ or : or ,. Ordinarily this would also capture these characters because of the brackets but because of the ?: modifier they won't be caught.

**Update**: whoops, true enough. ^ matches beginning of string in this context, not the symbol itself.

Comment: Wrong, `^` means "start of the input" (at least in the `g` mode)